# Why does my \n not work and how can i make it work

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does my \n not work and how can i make it work

```
x = "text1"
c = "text2"

b=[]
for i in range(5): 
    xx=(c + "  |  " + x + "\n")
    b.append(xx)

print (b)
```

Comment: what you expect to be an output?

Comment: You are printing the list instead of the contents in it. See answer from Aiven for how it should be done.

Comment: This looks fine what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to print out text instead of list then use `str.join`

```
# ...
print(''.join(b))

# or like this:
text = ''.join([(c + "  |  " + x + "\n") for _ in range(5)])
print(text)

# or python 3.6 style
text = ''.join(f"{c}  |  {x}\n" for _ in range(5))
```

Comment: thnx it works but what does this mean  -->   '.join(f

Comment: `f"{c}  |  {x}\n"` is string format introduced in python3.6. `str.join(list)` merge list and put str between items. `[a for a in list]` is list comprehension, just convenient way to make simple lists. Inside `join` you can omit square braces of list comprehension.